# Python Pint: set short representation of units as default

Tags: python, representation, pint

Pint units are represented by default with their full name:

```
>>> import pint
>>> ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
>>> q = ureg.Quantity('3.456 m^2')
>>> print(q)
3.456 meter ** 2
>>> print('The pretty representation is {:P}'.format(q))
The pretty representation is 3.456 meter²
```

From the docs and from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65682476/694360) it comes out that units can be represented in their short form, which is the way they are commonly represented in the real world:

```
>>> print(format(q,'~'))
3.456 m ** 2
>>> print('The pretty representation is {:~P}'.format(q))
The pretty representation is 3.456 m²
```

However, I would like to set the short representation as default, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this at the bottom of this section *String formatting* in the [tutorial](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#string-formatting). This is a minimal working example:

```py
import pint

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
ureg.default_format = '~' # Add this if you want to use abbreviated unit names.
accel = 1.3 * ureg['meter/second**2']
print(f'The acceleration is {accel}')
```

This outputs: `The acceleration is 1.3 m / s ** 2`

These are also valid options for short units: `~L` (LaTeX), `~H` (HTML) and `~P` (Pretty print).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's wrong, weak or non-pythonic, but it seems to work and I'm using this, until better solution arise:

```
import pint
pint.quantity.Quantity.__str__ = lambda self: format(self,'~')
```

After you add such line at the beginning of your script all the string representations of units are returned in short form (e.g. `mm` instead of `millimeter`).